# How to add external javascript in react app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I made a JavaScript particle animation and it works fine on a normal html website.
I tried implementing it into my react app using react helmet/useEffect but both didn't work and I don't know what's going on.

Here is my script:

```
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
canvas.style.width = '100%';
canvas.style.height = '100%';

const container = document.querySelector('.particles');
container.appendChild(canvas);

let particleArray;

class Particle {
    constructor(x, y, dirX, dirY, size, color) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.dirX = dirX;
        this.dirY = dirY;
        this.size = size;
        this.color = color;
        this.scale = .1;
        this.counter = 0;
    }
    draw() {
        var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(this.x, this.y, this.size / 8, this.x, this.y, this.size);
        gradient.addColorStop(0, 'white');
        gradient.addColorStop(1, 'white');

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.size, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        ctx.shadowColor = this.color;
        ctx.shadowBlur = 10;
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        
        ctx.fill();
    }
    update() {
        if (this.x + this.size > canvas.width || this.x - this.size < 0) {
            this.dirX = -this.dirX;
        }
        if (this.y + this.size > canvas.height || this.y - this.size < 0) {
            this.dirY = -this.dirY;
        }

        this.size += this.scale;
        this.counter += .1;

        if (this.counter > 3) {
            this.scale = -this.scale;
            this.counter = 0;
        }

        this.x += this.dirX;
        this.y += this.dirY;

        this.draw();
    }
}


function init() {
    particleArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        let size = Math.random() * 3;
        let x = Math.random() * (innerWidth - size * 2);
        let y = Math.random() * (innerHeight - size * 2);
        let dirX = (Math.random() * .4) - .2;
        let dirY = (Math.random() * .4) - .2;
        let colors = ['#721240']
        let color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];

        particleArray.push(new Particle(x, y, dirX, dirY, size, color));
    }
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);

    for (let i = 0; i < particleArray.length; i++) {
        particleArray[i].update();
    }
}

init();
animate();

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    canvas.width = innerWidth;
    canvas.height = innerHeight;
    init()
})
```

And here is how I tried to add it to my react app in App.js:

```
<div className="particles">
    {useScript("./assets/particles.js")}
</div>
```

useScript is a react function using useEffect:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

function useScript(url) {
    useEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement("script");

        script.src = url;
        script.async = false;

        document.body.appendChild(script);

        return () => {
            document.body.removeChild(script);
        };
    }, [url]);
}

export default useScript;
```

Please help I'm stuck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of injecting the script, why don't you directly inject the code itself in `useEffect`. That's worked for me on multiple occassions

This is my proposed code. `console.log()` things like canvas and particleArray at multiple places to get it right

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

function useScript(url) {
    useEffect(() => {
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

canvas.style.position = 'absolute';
canvas.style.width = '100%';
canvas.style.height = '100%';

const container = document.querySelector('.particles');
container.appendChild(canvas);

let particleArray;

class Particle {
    constructor(x, y, dirX, dirY, size, color) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.dirX = dirX;
        this.dirY = dirY;
        this.size = size;
        this.color = color;
        this.scale = .1;
        this.counter = 0;
    }
    draw() {
        var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(this.x, this.y, this.size / 8, this.x, this.y, this.size);
        gradient.addColorStop(0, 'white');
        gradient.addColorStop(1, 'white');

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.size, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        ctx.shadowColor = this.color;
        ctx.shadowBlur = 10;
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        
        ctx.fill();
    }
    update() {
        if (this.x + this.size > canvas.width || this.x - this.size < 0) {
            this.dirX = -this.dirX;
        }
        if (this.y + this.size > canvas.height || this.y - this.size < 0) {
            this.dirY = -this.dirY;
        }

        this.size += this.scale;
        this.counter += .1;

        if (this.counter > 3) {
            this.scale = -this.scale;
            this.counter = 0;
        }

        this.x += this.dirX;
        this.y += this.dirY;

        this.draw();
    }
}


function init() {
    particleArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        let size = Math.random() * 3;
        let x = Math.random() * (innerWidth - size * 2);
        let y = Math.random() * (innerHeight - size * 2);
        let dirX = (Math.random() * .4) - .2;
        let dirY = (Math.random() * .4) - .2;
        let colors = ['#721240']
        let color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];

        particleArray.push(new Particle(x, y, dirX, dirY, size, color));
    }
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);

    for (let i = 0; i < particleArray.length; i++) {
        particleArray[i].update();
    }
}

init();
animate();

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    canvas.width = innerWidth;
    canvas.height = innerHeight;
    init()
})
return ()=>{
   window.removeEventListener('resize', () => {
    canvas.width = innerWidth;
    canvas.height = innerHeight;
    init()
})
}
 
    }, [url]);
}

export default useScript;
```

Comment: Great I'm glad. Can you please upvote this so that the next person with a similar problem gets redirected here asap ? @Dr.Dark.Crystals